# Prove convergence/divergence of $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty ke^{-\sqrt k} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove the convergence/divergence of the following series.
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty ke^{-\sqrt k} $$
The root and ratio tests don't work because r = 1. That leaves the integral and comparison tests, but I cannot for the life of me find an expression that works for the comparison test. And the integral seems too complicated for a homework problem from this book. (I tried.) Could someone just point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: $ke^{-\sqrt{k}}=o\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$ and the series converges.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but what about $k^2e^{-k}$. I'm fairly confident that the series converges (because of the negative exponential).

Comment: Tubasbien, I don't understand what you mean by o (1/k^2). Sorry.

Comment: Jared, it does converge, but the original equation is eventually greater than k^2e^-k, so it doesn't prove convergence of the original equation.

Comment: This is a comparison test, this means that $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow +\infty}k^3e^{-\sqrt{k}}=0$ and since $\sum\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges, your series converges aswell.

Comment: $e^\sqrt{k} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{k}^i}{i!} > \frac{k^3}{6!} \implies k e^{-\sqrt{k}} <\frac{6!}{k^2} $

Comment: @BlueDiamond Yes I understand that $k^2e^{-k} < ke^{-\sqrt{k}}$ (eventually), but, I believe, $k^2e^{-k}$ is amenable to the integral test and can be shown to be "equivalent" via a change of indexes.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks so much Tubasbien! I was making it way more complicated than it needed to be. Would you mind posting your comment as the answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow +\infty}k^3e^{-\sqrt{k}}=0$ and since $\sum\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges, $\sum ke^{-\sqrt{k}}$ converges aswell.

Answer (score 0):

We can compare $k e^{-\sqrt{k}}$ and $\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)}$.
To do this, I assert that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{k^{2}(k+1)}{e^{\sqrt{k}}}=0$.

Note that by **L'hopital**'s rule again and again, we can calculate limit of $\dfrac{s^{4}(s^{2}+1)}{e^{s}}$ as follows.

> $\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{s^{4}(s^{2}+1)}{e^{s}}=\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{s^{6}+s^{4}}{e^{s}}=\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{6 s^{5}+4 s^{3}}{e^{s}}=\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{30 s^{4}+12 s^{2}}{e^{s}}=\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{120 s^{3}+24 s}{e^{s}}=\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{360 s^{2}+24}{e^{s}}=\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{720 s}{e^{s}}=\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{720}{e^{s}}=0$

Since $\sqrt{k}$ goes $\infty$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$, we can conclude that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{k^{2}(k+1)}{e^{\sqrt{k}}}=0$.

Thus, by definition of **limit**, we get there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k \ge n$ gives $\dfrac{k^{2}(k+1)}{e^{\sqrt{k}}}<1$.
Dividing both side to $k(k+1)$, $k e^{-\sqrt{k}}<\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)}$.

So $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k e^{-\sqrt{k}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} k e^{-\sqrt{k}}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} k e^{-\sqrt{k}} \le \sum_{k=0}^{n} k e^{-\sqrt{k}}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)} <\infty$